# Excel VBA - Getting Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

i had created a sheet where i have all sheet names then created a drop down of that data using data validation, everything was fine when i created this below code and checked, but it is throwing error when i am working on other drop down of sheet.

when i am clicking on other drop down of sheet, this code giving error "application-defined or object-defined error"

please help me on this, and also help me understand why this below code is giving error when didn't even executing this code.

```
Sub ListSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer

x = 2
sheets("all sheet names").Range("A:A").Clear
For Each ws In Worksheets
    sheets("all sheet names").Cells(x, 1) = ws.Name
    x = x + 1
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. It would be helpful to others if you explicitly state which line of code causes the error.Are you sure this is the EXACT code you are running? Did you change any spellings?

Comment: You have a problem because of `sheets` - this is a collection, and because in your code it has a lower case "s" it implies that somewhere else in your VBA project you have defined your own variable named `sheets`. Do a "Find" throughout the entire Project for `"sheets"`, and rename the variable to something else, see if this fixes the issue

Comment: @paulbica i had also noticed that "sheets" problem, and i replaced all "sheets" to "Sheets".... still it is in lower case.... stubborn sheets!

Comment: Unless I'm way off, 'Sheets' is a valid Excel Object 'A collection of all the sheets in the specified or active workbook'  see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/sheets-object-excel

Comment: I agree if it is lowercase in the 'real' code,then there must be a definition elsewhere. Did you search your ENTIRE VBA project for 'sheets'?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn i did replaced "sheets" with "Sheets", it is still in lower case

Comment: Yes, but confirm you did it throughout the ENTIRE project and not just that module.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn my code is in "Sheet1" instead of "module", could it be reason for error

Comment: The location of this code is not the problem, but in other VBA modules you have defined a variable called `sheets` (as in `Dim sheets As String` for example), and this declaration can be in any other Sub, Function, or Module. In the VBA editor you need to open the Find window (Ctrl + F), and search for the word `"sheets"`, click on **"Current Project"**, and check "Find Whole Word Only" and "Match Case", then click the button "Find Next" and look for a variable declaration similar to `Dim sheets As String` or `Dim sheets As Long`, etc

Comment: also, what exact line of code is throwing the error? when you see the error message click the Debug button and it will open the code with the specific line highlighted

Comment: @paulbica and WayneG.Dunn thank you both for your time and help...
can you please tell me why my code is running when i am not even using that code.... for example code throwing error is for another dropdown and it is throwing error when i am updating value of another dropdown...

Comment: This is what we're attempting to determine: if there are other objects somewhere else that are ambiguous (conflicting object names). Most likely, there is a problem in your code for the other drop-down(s), and not the code you posted

Comment: Do you have Option Explicit set in all of the code modules? if not, that could be contributing to the problem.

Comment: Re 'code running when not even using...' you would need to provide ALL your code! We have no clue what EVENTS you may have defined (i.e. On_Change?) or what code calls other code, etc.  As for your original issue, unless you can 100% convince (and answer) us that you have searched every piece of code in your entire project for 'sheets', then we can't help you.